# Unable to assign Model value to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I use an autocomplete to introduce the description of a product and get the ProductID  and the Price with a javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
      $("#Description").change(function () {
        $("#ProductID").val(Description_autocomplete_hidden.value);
        $("#Price").load('@Url.Action("GetPrice", "Product")', { id: parseInt($("#ProductID").val()) });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

The ProductID works fine, the action, e.g., “\Product\GetPrice\4” is correctly called but I am unable to assign the product price to the $(“#Price”).

The razor code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="label">@Html.Label("Product")</div>
  <div class="input">@Html.AutoComplete("Description","","Product","_Shared")</div>
</div>
<div id ="ProductID"></div>
<br />

<div class="row">
  <div class="label">@Html.Label("Price")</div>
  <div class="input">@Html.Editor("Price")</div>
</div>
```

The GetPrice() in the Product controller:

```
public string GetPrice(int id)
{
  return unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetByID(id).Pvp1.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Sorry Diodeus, I had not seen this functionality

Comment: @Joao, Can't suggest any thing until you post GetPrice method's code.

Comment: @Joao by the way what would you get if you entered this url \Product\GetPrice\4 in the browser?

Comment: @Bishnu Paudel, I have edited and added de GetPrice(). When I call it, it returns the correct price, e.g., "10" but when I watch $("#Price").val(), I see: ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Carlos is Right! The .load() function tries to set the inner HTML which doesn't work for a text field. You need to set textBox's value to make it work. Simply replace your line `$("#Price").load('@Url.Action("GetPrice", "Product")', { id: parseInt($("#ProductID").val()) });
      });`

With this:

```
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetPrice", "Product")', { id: parseInt($("#ProductID").val()) },
 function(result) {
        //set the value here    
        $("#Price").val(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document.

According to what is written there, jQuery `load` method cannot be used to set value attribute of your input.

Please use this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It will give you more options. Also in success callback you can use returned value wherever you want, in your case to assign value to input:

```
$("#Price").val(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
      $("#Description").change(function () {
        $("#ProductID").val(Description_autocomplete_hidden.value);
  $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetPrice", "Product")',
                        data: { id: parseInt($("#ProductID").val()) },
                        dataType: 'text',
                        type: 'get',
                        success: function (data) {
                           $("#Price").val(data); // 
                        }
                    });        
      });
    });
  });
```

try this